# SQL Query: grouping datetime as time slot

Tags: sql

I've a query having lot of datetime as result.

Suppose I want to count how much of these datetime are in a time slot like:

```
07:00 to 08:00
08:01 to 09:00
```

so I want something like this:

```
_______________________
| slot         | count
|______________|________
| 7:00 - 8:00  |   10
| 8:01 - 9:00  |    2
```

I really don't know what i can do to have this result.
I've tried something like this but obv i get error:

```
SELECT  something
FROM    something   
WHERE       
        CAST(DATEPART(hour, <data>) as varchar(2)) + ':' +  CAST(DATEPART(minute, <data>)as varchar(2)) between <slot1> and <slot2>
```

TIPS: probably I'll get the time slots dynamically from the report services.

Comment: DB server please?  SQL Server or Oracle or MySQL..

Comment: @DipenduPaul Sorry: sql server

Comment: In which way are the times stored in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is query to accomplish what you seem to looking for:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(HH, time) AS VARCHAR(2))+':00 - '+CAST(DATEPART(HH, time)+1 AS VARCHAR(2))+':00', COUNT(*)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY DATEPART(HH, time)
```

Here is code at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b00397/8)

[EDIT]:

AS per the new requirement, below query can accomplish what you want:

```
SELECT (CAST(DATEPART(HH, time) AS VARCHAR(2)) + 
            CASE WHEN DATEPART(MI, time) <= 30 THEN ':00 - '+CAST(DATEPART(HH, time) AS VARCHAR(2))+':30' 
                 ELSE ':30 - '+CAST(DATEPART(HH, time)+1 AS VARCHAR(2))+':00' END) AS  r,
       COUNT(*) 
FROM your_table
GROUP BY
       (CAST(DATEPART(HH, time) AS VARCHAR(2)) + 
            CASE WHEN DATEPART(MI, time) <= 30 THEN ':00 - '+CAST(DATEPART(HH, time) AS VARCHAR(2))+':30' 
                 ELSE ':30 - '+CAST(DATEPART(HH, time)+1 AS VARCHAR(2))+':00' END)
```

Here is the code at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93c66/11)

If you do not want to use `CASE` statement two times as in the above query then you can do a `GROUP BY` in an outer query enclosing the current as an inner query as below:

```
SELECT r, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM
(
    SELECT (CAST(DATEPART(HH, time) AS VARCHAR(2)) + 
            CASE WHEN DATEPART(MI, time) <= 30 THEN ':00 - '+CAST(DATEPART(HH, time) AS VARCHAR(2))+':30' 
                 ELSE ':30 - '+CAST(DATEPART(HH, time)+1 AS VARCHAR(2))+':00' END) AS  r
    FROM your_table
) tab
GROUP BY r
```

Here is the code at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93c66/10)

Let me know if it solved your problem.

Comment: You think its possible to divide the slot for half hour?? like

9 - 9:30 | 9:30 - 10 | etc..

Comment: it can be done with CASE `statement`. Keeping the HOUR extraction as it is, we need to extract the minute as well and using `CASE` statement then we need to check if it is less than 30 then ":00" should be concatenated else ":30" should be concatenated.

Comment: I don't want you waste your time... but when you have some time to spend you can write the code?? I will be really happy with you. Otherwise, no problem. Thanks Anyway!!!!!!!

Comment: Sure I will...this is a community, so concept wastage of time doesn't fit in...enough of preaching

Comment: Thanks for the code, but the result is: `10 - 10:30 | 11 - 11:30`

but i need `10 - 10:30 | 10:30 - 11:00 | 11:00 - 11:30 | 11:30 - 12:00 etc etc `

I think its s abit more difficult

Comment: no it's not difficult, I guess some bug crept in, I'll check

Comment: Now you can check, the first parameter of `DATEPART` function was wrong. I have corrected it.